# ndb datastore gives me error with repeated=True and projection

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a ndb model class like this :

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    works = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    created_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I used `repeated=True` because I want to save data to works field in a list. But when I query works like this :

```
user = User.query().fetch(projection=[User.works])
```

I couldn't get what I want. If I look at `user`, I get this :

```
[User(key=Key('User', 5629499534213120), works=[u'A'], _projection=('works',)), User(key=Key('User', 5629499534213120), works=[u'B'], _projection=('works',)), User(key=Key('User', 5629499534213120), works=[u'C'], _projection=('works',)), User(key=Key('User', 5629499534213120), works=[u'D'], _projection=('works',)).......................
```

Why couldn't I get this :

```
[User(key=Key('User', 5629499534213120), works=[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'], _projection=('works',))
```

And what can I do? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Just a quick tip: Use `auto_now` instead of `auto_now_add` for your `updated_date` field. Otherwise, it will only be updated once. More information [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time)

Answer (score 2):

Projection returns list of entities, not in the way you want it to be. Look at here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection

You can loop through the results as:

```
for u in user:
    print u.works # To get value of 'works'
    print u.key # Key of the entity, you can access other properties from this key.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok how can I filter with projection query ?

Comment: It is a list, you can use list comprehension as: value = [u for u in user if u.works == "somestring"].